# Accelerometer selection?

Tags: accelerometer

I would like to design a circuit which when moves should give out a voltage. So I would like to choose an accelerometer for this application. I wish to go for single-axis accelerometer which is quite good enough for my application. I need to understand what are all the parameters that we need to understand before going for the selection.

Comment: What causes the circuit to move and how fast does it move? When it is moving at constant speed an accelerometer will give no signal any more.

Comment: May i know the reason for devoting the question?

Comment: start by reading a datasheet, then ask about the parameters you don't understand. As it is, this question reduces to "please tell me everything about accelerometers".

Comment: @Andy: I will be placing the device in an object which moves at different speeds in a single direction in fact in a horizontal direction.

Comment: Then what causes the "object" to move and how would an accelerometer give a signal out when velocity is constant? If you want answers, please don't ask why I'm asking a question; make the assumption I'm trying to help you and not trying to steal your ideas.

Comment: Never Andy! I was just trying to keep it little broader. No issues. I will placing in a vehicle which moves with different velocities and it moves only on the roads.

Comment: Then why aren't you using the vehicle itself to produce an output when it moves? This would seem much easier because you could use an inductive sensor on the wheel that generates pulses (for instance).

Comment: The most obvious selection criteria are probably G range and accuracy appropriate to your application, cost, and either a package you can work with or availability on/of a breakout board.

Comment: Can somebody reopen the question??

Comment: These are the main parameters for selecting an accelerometer (in this order): 1. g Range, 2. Protocol Communication, 3. Noise Level, 4. Axis number

Answer (score 1):

Like most sensors, accelerometers are subject to offset and range errors as well as noise. Each of these parameters usually has a temperature dependence, too.

In addition, since you need to mathematically integrate acceleration to get velocity, there are additional considerations. A constant error in acceleration (because of offset or scale errors) results in a velocity value that drifts indefinitely with time. And the noise in acceleration results in a "random walk" of the velocity value that also grows with time.

There are various ways to deal with these real-world considerations, but it's too broad a topic to get into without knowing more about your specific application.